# Python Menu option only works once

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and have been experimenting. I've created a simple program with a menu so my grandson can practice his multiplication tables.

I run the script and a menu appears. Menu option allows a multiplication table quiz to be launched.

Each menu option executes a function which imports the relevant script, runs through asking the questions and keeps score. If all questions are answered an appropiate message is printed and if not, another message is printed.

Now the issue I'm facing is that if say for example the two times table is selected, it works on the first run but when the same option is selected again to 'retake' the quiz, it doesn't launch the script. It just executes the print statement.

Having researched online etc, the import only works once. Is there a way of reloading the function so the script i.e two times table runs again??

I've included some code below:

```
def onetimes(): import one_timestable...etc

menu = {}
menu['1']= "One Timestable"
menu['2']= "Two Timestable"
menu['3']= "Three Timestable"
menu['4']= "Four Timestable".......etc

while True:
    options=menu.keys()
    for entry in options:
        print (entry, menu[entry])
        print()
    selection=input("Please choose your quiz:")
    if selection =='1':
        print("You've chosen the one timestable quiz")
        print()
        onetimes()
    elif selection == '2':
        print("You've chosen the two timestable quiz")
        print()
        twotimes()
    elif selection == '3':
        print("You've chosen the three timestable quiz")
        print()
        threetimes()....etc
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make a [mre]. That whole `...etc` stuff makes it hard to find the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The menu options work only once. You can't execute the script under the option again. So if you execute option 1, the one times table script runs, but won't run again. The function which is defined only imports the script once. I need to get it to reload so it's available to try again. I can't explain it any easier than that